# Handling errors in a function that converts a string to an integer

Tags: c++

I was just trying to implement my own function for string to `int` conversion. 
My function is as follows:

```
int func(string s)
{
    if error return -1;
    else do something and return the value 
}
```

I just have one doubt, what if my string was s = "-1", then how would I differentiate between the "-1" returned for the error and for the right conversion of the string. Thanks for your help. I hope my question was clear enough.

Comment: You can't. Your function design is flawed.

Comment: Why not just throw an exception if the string doesn't represent a number?

Comment: This shows why error handling is always tricky.  In the general case, any function has two outputs: (1) a success/failure value, and (2) a return value.  It's always tempting to try to combine the two, because returning the two things separately is a nuisance, it's never as convenient.  But if you combine the two (as you're trying to here), and if the set of normal return values is not distinct from the success/error distinction, you end up with an unresolvable ambiguity.

Comment: If you are using C, then change function prototype. int func(string s, int *out); Retuen 0 for success and -1 for failure. Sore the output value in *out.

Comment: Here's a related riddle: "Why can't a Unix system operate just before midnight on Wednesday, December 31, 1969?"  Answer: "Because at 23:59:59 the `time()` system call would return -1, and it would look like an error."

Comment: Another possibility is a [`std::optional<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), but I'd go with the exception.

Comment: Pick C or C++ as this changes the implementation.

Comment: Us e the tag for that "c.c++" language, not for the two languages C and C++, if you want a solution for "c.c++". I'd also be interested to see a link to the specification.

Comment: Maybe look at [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to see how this is done in C++.

Answer (score 4):

You have several options with different trade-offs.

**1. Exception**. Throw an exception in the error case. Exceptions need not be caught directly at the call site, but can be handled further up in the call hierarchy, where you have more context to deal with the error. I would even say that if you always wrap your function call in try-catch blocks, you might misunderstand the advantage of exceptions.

```
int func(const std::string& s);
```

**2. Optional return value.** [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), available in C++17 (or before as `boost::optional` or a technical specification (TS)). This is to explicitly state that not returning a value is a valid case that has to be considered when calling the function.

```
std::optional<int> func(const std::string& s);
```

The cool thing is the explicit operator bool that allows for this idiom:

```
if (std::optional<int> i = func("hello")) // or even auto
       use(*i);
```

**3. Pointer return value.** With semantics similar to the previous point, this can be needed when a stored element is returned, e.g. in a search. If it is not found, `nullptr` is returned. In contrast to `std::optional`, this has the disadvantage that it requires memory/lifetime management (either the object is guaranteed to outlive the call, or it is allocated dynamically). Don't ever return a pointer that has to be explicitly deleted by the caller, if you really need dynamic allocation use `std::unique_ptr`. Keep in mind that dynamic allocation is expensive and almost always overkill for small objects such as `int`. Also, you need to think about const-correctness.

```
int* func(const std::string& s);
const int* func(const std::string& s);
std::unique_ptr<int> func(std::string& s);
```

**4. The check-and-output-parameter idiom**. Have a function that takes an output parameter. If it generates a value, it writes the result to that parameter and returns true, otherwise it returns false.

```
bool func(int& out);
```

This allows for invocations as follows. The drawback is that you cannot directly initialize the object (and thus cannot use `const`-qualified, default-constructed or non-assignable objects, for example).

```
int value;
if (func(value))
    use(value);
```

**5. Assertion**. This is something that many people overlook, especially those who come from languages like Java, where most errors are categorically handled with exceptions. If the only case where an invalid value would be returned is an incorrect invocation of the function -- i.e. a logic error (not to say bug) in your program -- then it's often more advisable to make this recognizable as soon as possible. Debuggers will stop immediately at failed assertions, while your productive code comes with them entirely optimized away.

```
int func(const std::string& s);
```

Assertions are great to check pre- or postconditions of functions. They are especially useful to signal errors that cannot be meaningfully handled at runtime. If they fail, it means your program logic is broken, and since this shouldn't have happened in the first place, there is no good way to recover from the situation. Because your application is in an unexpected state, executing further code may make matters worse.

Answer (score 1):

Your function design could be:

```
int func(string s, int *out)
{
    if error return -1;
    else {
        do something and set *out to the value;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

As comments have outlined, the return value is overloaded for `-1` if it is to represent both a valid value and an error. As there is no integer value that can represent both, an additional return value is needed. In this design, the return value of the function represents the success or failure and the `*out` parameter returns the result. Of couse you can swap these two (the parameter receives the success or failure and the return value the value).

Comment: A very common convention is to return `0` for success, non-zero for error. That's the reverse of the common zero=false, nonzero=true convention for booleans, but it can be useful to encode more information in a non-zero failure code.

Comment: @Keith-Thompson, the alternative is "silent failure" such as `atoi` that returns `0` also if it can't convert the value.

Comment: Yes, that's an alternative -- also known as a *bad idea*.

Answer (score 1):

You could just throw an exception.

```
int func (string const & input)
{
  if (error)
    throw std::runtime_error("stuff happenend")
  else
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `boost::lexical_cast` and let the caller handle `bad cast exceptions`.

```
// will throw bad_lexical_cast  if any issue.
int convert(const std::string& num) {
    return boost::lexical_cast<int>(num);
}


int main()
{
    try {
        std::cout << convert("1") << "\n";
        std::cout << convert("-1") << "\n";
        std::cout << convert("abc") << "\n";
    } catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast& blc) {
        std::cout << blc.what() << "\n";
    }

 return 0;
}
```

This is simple and well tested.

Simpler way would be just use `boost::lexical_cast<T>()` without the `convert` function which only gives you a wrapper;

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/WjuWoL)

Comment: Why not use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)?

Comment: @juanchopanza masochism. It's the new black.

Comment: @juanchopanza because lexical_cast is more  flexible with the kind of conversions. [check this link with more info about lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html#boost_lexical_cast.performance.tests_description). It also gives you uniform interface across many different types.

Comment: The kind of conversions? All is needed is `string` to `int`.

Comment: Why have a toolbox if only need a screwdriver right? I'll use the same screwdriver size with all my needs. This covers `string` to `int`, which was requested. You asked why? you have the answer there, including the original from the post. Also if you do not have C++11 compiler, then what? `boost`.

Comment: No, you're using a toolbox. The screwdriver is `std::stoi`.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. This solution covers the requested case. `lexical_cast` or `stoi` or any other flavour are extensively covered already.